# RubyMine 8 doesn't detect Rails gem after installation, cannot create project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubymine

After I installed Rails 4.2.5.1 in RubyMine welcome page, RubyMine doesn't detect Rails, and I cannot create projects.

**RubyMine Welcome Page**

[image]

And **Console**.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to select Rails Version here? http://i.stack.imgur.com/xe5mb.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create rails projects is through the command line.

1) Go to the folder where you want to create the project

`->$ cd development`

2) Create rails project

`->$ rails new project_name`

3) Open project in Rubymine

`->$ mine .`

This will open Rubymine to your current project.

I work with Rubymine all the time, and it's best not to worry about the gems it can't install. If you absolutely need the gem, first make sure `gem install rails` works. Then attempt to install it using the little pop up about not having all of the installed gems. You may need to uninstall rails to fix the issue.

If the reason you want the gems is to use the debugger, I suggest using the `byebug` gem. It's a great gem for debugging and I personally prefer it over the rubymine debugger.